# Convex combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

This question popped up in my head while doing a similar question.

Let $A$ and $B$ be two invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Define $C(t) \colon[0,1]\rightarrow M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ as
$$C(t) = (1-t)A+tB$$

Certainly $C(t)$ may not be invertible. For example if $A=-B$. Then $C \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)$ is not invertible.

I would like to know under what conditions can we guarantee invertibilty of $C(t)$ for all $t$ or at least infinite values of $t$?

**Edit**: I'm looking for general conditions on something like determinant, trace, eigenvalues, etc. The condition that $A$ is a scalar multiple of $B$ is an un-interesing case.

Comment: Certainly for $A=B$. Or, say, for $A=I$ and $B=2I$.

Comment: The Gershgorin circle theorem lets you say something about diagonally dominant matrices

Comment: @DietrichBurde, $A=B$ is un-interesting case.

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes, but $A=I$ and $B=2I$ does not satisfy $A=B$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Agreed. It's a nice example to show that $C(t)$ is invertible for all $t$. However I'm looking for more general conditions and not just examples.

Comment: @SahibaArora Good point. You should say this also in the question, what kind of general conditions you would like/accept.

Comment: Another condition worth noting is that if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, then $C(t)$ will be positive definite (and invertible) for all $t \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always have an infinite (indeed, uncountable) number of invertible matrices along the segment between $A$ and $B$.  Determinant is a continuous function of the entries of a matrix.  So in some neighborhood of both $A$ and $B$ you are guaranteed invertibility, since the determinant of $\epsilon A + (1-\epsilon)B$ will vary from det A by only a small amount, and therefore not be zero.

One case where you're guaranteed invertiblity is when $A$ and $B$ have a complete set of equal eigenvectors, where the corresponding eigenvalue pairs all have the same sign (and are nonzero).  In this case, the eigenvalues are given by $\lambda_i=t\lambda_{iA}+(1-t)\lambda_{iA}$, and since the eigenvalue pairs have the same sign, none of the eigenvalues of $C$ will be zero.

Comment: More than that: you'll get an invertible matrix for all but finitely many values of $t$, since the determinant is a polynomial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, that's true.

Comment: This is certainly interesting.

Comment: @SahibaArora, I added a case where you are guaranteed invertibility for entire path.

Answer (score 1):

$\det C(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$. Indeed it is closely
related to the characteristic polynomial of $B^{-1}A$. As it's
a polynomial, and $\det C(0)\ne0$ and $\det C(1)\ne0$ it only vanishes at at most $n$ values of $t$. Unless $A=B$ the polynomial won't be constant, and over $\Bbb C$ at least, there will be some solution of $\det C(t)=0$.

Comment: You mean $\det(C(t))$, presumably.

Comment: But for $C(t)=(1+t)I$, with $A=I$, $B=2I$, we have $\det C(t)=1+t\ge 1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde this answer doesn't focus so much on the interval $t \in [0,1]$, but it does consider $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: A notable consequence (which answers one of the questions posed) is that either $C(t)$ will be singular for all $t \in \Bbb R$, or it will be singular for at most finitely many values of $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $C(0)$ and $C(1)$ are never singular or are you saying that it has to be always singular for at most finite values of $t$?

Comment: @SahibaArora right.  If $A$ and $B$ are taken to be non-invertible, then we could end up getting a singular matrix for all $t$, but again we might have a singular matrix for at most finitely many $t$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have mentioned in the question that $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices.

Comment: @SahibaArora sorry for the confusion.  I thought you might appreciate the slightly more general statement.